# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I upgrade the **networkx** by `sudo pip install networkx --upgrade` and now my networkx is up-to-date.

```
$ pip freeze | grep 'networkx'
networkx==1.11
```

But I encounter the issue: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'min_weighted_dominating_set'` while running the following codes.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.path_graph(5)
s = nx.min_weighted_dominating_set(G, weight=None)
```

PS: **`min_weighted_dominating_set`** is described [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.dominating_set.min_weighted_dominating_set.html#networkx.algorithms.approximation.dominating_set.min_weighted_dominating_set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import min_weighted_dominating_set

import networkx as nx
G = nx.path_graph(5)
s = min_weighted_dominating_set(G, weight=None)
```

I'm not sure why it needs a special import...  I wonder if that's an accident or intentional for networkx.

Comment: awesome, it does work for me!

Comment: Right. Obvious but not so obvious! :))  - Actually, the whole link is **'networkx.algorithms.approximation.dominating_set.min_weighted_dominating_set'**, and in fact, the function *'min_weighted_dominating_set()'* is in file *'dominating_set.py'*, however it can be also imported directly from the folder!  I will never fully understand how importing works in PY!